# Kafka producer looses queued messages when broker restarts

Tags: kafka

I have no much experience on the subject and maybe doing something wrong.

The problem occurs when I stop Kafka broker and after a pause start it again.
Some seconds after broker starts my producer issues errors: "topic does not exist".
Due to this error all the offline buffered messages get lost.
Shortly the error dissapears and the consecutive messages are produced.

If I change "auto.create.topics.enable" server property to "true", the error "topic does not exist" keeps occuring after broker restart, but the buffered messages are produced as expected.

I suppose that if automatic topic creation is allowed, the error "topic does not exist" is considered transient and the producer repeats sending messages until the error is gone. Otherwise no repeats are made and the buffered messages get lost.

Can I do something to use "auto.create.topics.enable" = false and not to loose messages?

Running kafka_2.13-3.4.0 on WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04.1
and using C++ client with librdkafka v2.1.1 on Windows 10.
The settings are: delivery.timeout.ms=86400000, retries=2147483647, acks=all.
The topic is created with replication-factor 1, partitions 1.